# I want to convert translation curl command to ruby

Tags: ruby, api, curl

I want to using google translation v3 REST api in ruby,
but I couldn't include authentication.

google translation page: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/quickstart-v3

Example curl command on this page:

```
curl -X POST \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data "{
     source_language_code: 'en',
     target_language_code: 'ja',
     contents: ['hello']
}" "https://translation.googleapis.com/v3beta1/projects/project-id/locations/global:translateText"
```

I can't do `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token` part of this example code.

`-H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)`

Based on the following:

```
v3_url = "https://translation.googleapis.com/v3beta1/projects/#{ENV['GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID']}{/locations/global:translateText"


response = HTTParty.post(
    v3_url,
    headers: {
        "Authorization" => "Bearer",
        "Content-Type" => "application/json"
    },
    body: {
        source_language_code: 'en',
        target_language_code: 'ja',
        contents: ['hello']
    }
)
```

I tried

1:

```
"Authorization" => "Bearer" + system(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)
```

2:

```
"Authorization" => "Bearer", "#{system(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)}"
```

3:

```
Authorization" => "Bearer" + `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token`
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Didn't look deeper into it, but noticed that you're not adding a space, so your Authorization will look like `BearerABCD` instead of `Bearer ABCD` like it should.

Comment: The third one should be correct if space is added. The first one is missing quotes, the second one misuses comma for concatenation which it does not do. I'd probably do ``"Bearer #{`gcloud auth....`}"``

Comment: I got status 401 to 400,
request body is not correct,  but I passed to authentication at following space after "bearer".
```
"Authorization" => "Bearer " + `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token`,
```

Thank you Kimmo Lehto and Amadan!
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by the following method:

```
"Authorization" => "Bearer " + `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token`
```

thank you Kimmo Lehto and Amadan.

The code that can be executed is as follows:

```
v3_url = "https://translation.googleapis.com/v3beta1/projects/project-id/locations/global:translateText"

body = {
    source_language_code: 'en',
    target_language_code: 'ja',
    contents: ['hello']
}.to_json

response = HTTParty.post(
    v3_url,
    headers: {
        "Authorization" => "Bearer " + `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token`,
        "Content-Type" => "application/json"
    },
    body: body
)
puts response.body
```